# discord member.status won't change as time goes

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title mentioned, I've wrote some code that will get the status of users in the server every five minutes. But what actually happened is that it will only show the status of the time I started the program, and kept sending back the same information every five minutes. Can anyone help me? here are some of my codes

```
online = []
chan_mem = channel.members
for member in chan_mem:
    mem_stat = member.status
    if member.bot == False:
        if str(mem_stat) in ['online', 'dnd', 'mobile']:
            online.append(member.id)
        print(f'{member.name}:{mem_stat}')
```

Comment: you're not printing online

Comment: I don't understand the problem can you give us some outputs?

Comment: for ex, i turned on the program at 11:00 p.m. , the bot will then return the status of each member in the server, which is all right. But when it gives another return at 11:05 p.m. , it will be same as the one given at 11:00, although the status of the members has changed. Same will happen every five minutes, giving always the same return. (outputs are generating

Comment: 11:30
tsai:online, lalalalalala:offline, Louis Liu:offline, Chill_In_Summer:offline, heiheihei:idle, 楊浩軒:offline, 陳奕豪:offline, Xu Chen:offline
[702533620308508690]

11:35
tsai:online, lalalalalala:offline, Louis Liu:offline, Chill_In_Summer:offline, heiheihei:idle, 楊浩軒:offline, 陳奕豪:offline, Xu Chen:offline
[702533620308508690]
this is what i got although i changed two of my accounts' status.